# Build logic in AutoHotKey based on content of GUI

Tags: autohotkey

I'm completely new to AHK and I'm trying to find out if AHK can be used as a solution to a problem that I currently have regarding data export from a software tool as I'm struggling to understand what functionality and flexibility you can reach with AHK.

As I don't want to spend too much time in vain for researching and trying stuff out myself with AHK, I would appreciate it if you could evaluate the fit of AHK to the following problem situation.

In the GUI I have a view like this:

[image]

I'd like to export each image in both lists one by one by right-clicking the image and then follow along the shortcut menu.
The number of menu items is very flexible on each list so there could be few or even more.
Is it therefore possible to have some kind of function in AHK to assess the number of listed items beforehand and then have a loop that will be executed *x* times depending on the number of items?

Comment: Hard to say without being able to see that program myself, but at the very least the low tech solution of just moving the mouse in a predefined way to right click export all the images is surely possible. There could be better solutions though. Any chance those images are located somewhere on the disk? Or are they just in memory inside that program?

Comment: The program itself is the Heidelberg Eye Explorer (v1). Unforunately, I cannot show you more due to sensitive data.

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly but it's not an issue to export all images with a certain sequence of key strokes. That, I have already achieved. 
What I rather want is to build a logic with the information that is presented to me in the GUI and depending on what is displayed I want to export the images in a different way (different file format etc.).